# MySQL change database + tables charset & collation from UTF8 to UTF8mb4

Tags: mysql, database, utf-8, character-encoding

I currently have a MySQL database with the following settings:

```
character_set_client: utf8
character_set_connection: utf8
character_set_database: utf8
character_set_filesystem: binary
character_set_results: utf8
character_set_server: latin1
character_set_system: utf8
collation_connection: utf8_general_ci 
collation_database: utf8_general_ci  
collation_server: latin1_swedish_ci
```

I want to support emoji's and other languages (like Chinese) in the database. Currently this is not working, those characters are automatically converted to a `?`.

I created a test database with `charset` & `collation` `utf8mb4(_general_ci)` and a table with the same settings. Emojis work here. However, when I change the database settings to `utf8(_general_ci)` and leave the table as `utf8mb4(_general_ci)`, emojis are still working, while this is not the case with my main database.

If I change my main database settings to `charset` + `collation` `utf8mb4(_general_ci)`, and the tables as well, would that work?

And for database-access, will anything else have to be changed, such as `character_set_connection` or `collation_connection`?
I know on my JavaScript server, the connection is configured as `utf8`, I assume this has to be `utf8mb4`.

All current `utf8(_general_ci)` data, will that be kept intact when changing to `utf8mb4(_general_ci)`?

Answer (score 1):

Correctly stored utf8 characters will convert correctly to utf8mb4.

You should also specify that the connections are utf8mb4.

See [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for discussion of 'question mark'.

To convert all the char/text columns to utf8mb4:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

To convert one column:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN col ... CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is what I needed. Then there's another thing. The database runs on 2 separate servers, and is synchronised using `master-master replication`. I've seen that the column-settings are changed on both, but not the table-settings. Is it okay to do this on both databases, or will this break anything? Thanks!

Comment: @JeroenJK - It seems strange that the servers would not be identical.  Exactly what commands did you perform?  A problem _may_ occur if you later add a column without specifying a charset/collation -- if it picks up the _different_ `DEFAULT` one each machine.